# ERROR php Trying to get users to display everytime i input their id

Tags: php, html, oop, pdo

Im trying to make a profile.php page that if the user is logged out and inputs the url of a member manually some of the users (name, email etc should display). if the user is logged in his profile should have the option to log out and if he enters another users email the other users name etc should display. thanks for helping im always getting (User doesn;t exist)

```
session_start();
include_once 'php/classes/class.user.php';

echo var_dump($_SESSION);
echo var_dump($_GET);

$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

if(isset($_GET['uid'])){

    if(check_user($uid)){//move code to function check_user() user class
        echo "True";
    }else{
        echo "False";
    }

}else if(isset($_SESSION['uid'],$_SESSION['login'])){

    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $user = new User();

    echo "Hello <br/><br/>". $user->get_fullname($uid) ."
        <a href='profile.php?q=logout'>LOGOUT</a>";
}else{
    echo "User not set";
}

if (isset($_GET['q'])){

    $user->user_logout();
    header("location: index.php");

}
```

**Class user where i get the functions from**

```
include "db_config.php";

class User{

    public $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
                exit;
        }
    }

    /*** for login process ***/
    public function check_login($emailusername, $password){

        $password = md5($password);
        $sql2="SELECT uid from users WHERE uemail='$emailusername' or uname='$emailusername' and upass='$password'";

        //checking if the username is available in the table
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql2);
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $count_row = $result->num_rows;

        if ($count_row == 1) {
            // this login var will use for the session thing
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $user_data['uid'];
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function check_user(){

        $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
        $sql5="SELECT * from users WHERE uid='$uid'";

        //checking if the username is available in the table
        $result1 = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql5);
        $user_data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
        $count_row1 = $result1->num_rows;

        if ($count_row1 == 1) {
            // this login var will use for the session thing
            echo "True";
        }else{
            echo "False";
            }
        }

    /*** for showing the username or fullname ***/
    public function get_fullname($uid){
        $sql3="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql3);
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo $user_data['fullname'], "<br/>";
        echo $user_data['uemail'], "<br/>";
        echo $user_data['uname'], "<br/>";
        echo $user_data['uid'], "<br/>";
    }

    /*** starting the session ***/
    public function get_session(){
        return $_SESSION['login'];
    }

    public function user_logout() {
        $_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

**INDEX.php PHP CODE **

```
<?php
```

session_start();
    include_once 'php/classes/class.user.php';

```
$user = new User();
$log = $_SESSION['uid'];
if ($user->get_session()){
    header("Location: profile.php?=".$log."");
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    extract($_REQUEST);
    $login = $user->check_login($emailusername, $password);
    if ($login) {
        // Registration Success
        $log_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
        header("location: profile.php?=".$log_id."");

    } else {
        // Registration Failed
        echo 'Wrong username or password';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which methods of error checking are you using, if any? `session_start();` loaded also?

Comment: @Fred-ii- at the moment im just echo-ing out the errors

Comment: where is something like $user = new User();

Comment: @JelleKeizer i just put it forgot to include it when i made this post. sorry

Comment: if($user->get_session())  get_session doesnt return true or false, it returns a session value

Comment: @JelleKeizer that piece of code is when i log in actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'php/classes/class.user.php';

if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
    $user = new User();
    if($user->check_user($uid){//move code to function check_user() user class
        echo "True";
    }else{
        echo "False";
    }
}else if(isset($_SESSION['uid'],$_SESSION['login'])){
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $user = new User();
    echo "Hello <br/><br/>". $user->get_fullname($uid) ."
        <a href='profile.php?q=logout'>LOGOUT</a>";
    }else{
        echo "User not set";
    }

}
```

And in your code you should prepare the queries, or at least use `mysqli->real_escape_string`

Comment: you should make sure they have values `var_dump($_SESSION)` and `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: You are using isset() on GET, then reading from SESSION.  should be  $uid = $_GET['uid'] before check_user()

Comment: This was a typo Thanks @MrZebra

Comment: I guess im getting what i want to do but the content from DB is Not diplaying :array(0) { } array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } User not set

Comment: You can see one of them is empty and it should be `uid` not `id`

Comment: @Love_PHP I see  but in your dump it shows `id` shouldnt it be `uid` ?

Comment: @meda i can't seem to find where i went wrong. all the values i put its UID not ID :(

Comment: in your browser `INDEX.php?uid=123`

Comment: @Love_PHP sorry fell asleep, please tell me that it is solved

Comment: @meda i fixed it brother thanks for you help anyways much respect

Comment: @meda i wrote on chat i have one quick question